# Sign In With Slack - Invalid scopes: identity.basic, identity.avatar

Tags: oauth-2.0, slack, slack-api

I've set up my slack app to be installed using Oauth2.0 successfully calling

```
https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=<myAppsClientId>&scope=chat:write,commands,incoming-webhook,users:read&user_scope=chat:write,users:read
```

but when i try to use Sign In With Slack (So user can manage their slack on my web app) I use

```
https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize?scope=identity.basic,identity.avatar&client_id=<myAppsClientId>
```

The user gets the error on the slack url (before being redirected to my app):

```
Error details
  Invalid permissions requested
  Invalid scopes: identity.basic, identity.avatar
```

Since the add to slack and sign in with slack both call the same uri, im assuming the scope params are what separate the two. Not sure where Im going wrong because I followed the docs and used the button they generated for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I actually was able to get it to work by *NOT* using v2 for Sign In With Slack. But I *HAD* to use v2 for Add to Slack.

So using `/oauth/v2/authorize` and `/api/oauth.v2.access` for add to slack
and `/oauth/authorize` and `/api/oauth.access` for signin with slack

I don't think it should work like this but it's the only combo that's working.

Comment: Spend few hours to debug this. This is the correct answer and it's kinda crazy

Comment: any official aknowledgement of this behavior?

Comment: This is not correct and would be deprecated with Slack pushing to move to the new oAuth endpoints I'\d assume. Eric C's comment should be correct, have tried this and verified it works

Answer (score 9):

I don't know that this is the correct fix, but I encountered the same issue and I was able to get it working by renaming the 'scope' parameter to 'user_scope'

Comment: Hmm, I still get an error `Invalid permissions requested Invalid scope: user_scope`

Comment: The user_scope parameter is only available on the v2 SIWS URLs, but this worked for me as well

Comment: The selected answer worked, but I'd be more inclined to use this one. Which also works.
@slotdp02 Eric meant to say that the param name should be user_scope instead of scope, not the value. Value would still be whatever you originally intended

`https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize?user_scope=identity.basic,identity.avatar&client_id=<myAppsClientId>`

Comment: This should be the correct answer based on the current [documentation for the new OAuth flow](https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2#asking): "The `scope` list requests scopes for your app's bot user. If you have specific need for a user token (say, to act on behalf of a user), provide a `user_scope` parameter with requested user scopes instead of, or in addition to, the `scope` parameter." Since both `identity.basic` and `identity.avatar` are user scopes, the `user_scope` param is the right param to use.